# Apostilles on British Citizenship Paperwork

Tags: uk-citizenship

When applying for British Citizenship from abroad - what documents need to be apostilled? The guide doesn't mention any having to be.

Comment: Which guide are you using?

Comment: @phoog MN1. Registration for under 18s.

Comment: As far as I can tell it appears that the UK does not require apostilles on foreign documents, but I do not understand why, and (more importantly to you and you're question) I can't find an official source for this.  If I do, I'll post an answer.